# get gmail categories on thunderbird

Tags: thunderbird

GMail introduced a very good feature of automatically filtering emails into categories like primary, social, promotion, forums, updates.

Is there anyway to get this filtering in thunderbird in anyway ? (for example, tag, category, or even folder)

Comment: The close-vote reason says. "Thunderbird is not packaged in *nix distributions". Here are [some](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/extra/x86_64/thunderbird/) [counterexamples](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/icedove) [I](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/thunderbird) [found](https://apps.fedoraproject.org/packages/thunderbird) [without](http://packages.slackware.com/?r=slackware-current&p=mozilla-thunderbird-38.0.1-i586-1.txz) [really](https://packages.gentoo.org/package/mail-client/thunderbird) [trying](https://software.opensuse.org/package/MozillaThunderbird).

Comment: @MichaelHomer have you heard of Ubuntu (the most popular linux distro) ? ubuntu comes with thunderbird, so this question is valid, it is valid to ask questions related to the use of software on *nix distro

Comment: I'm on your side, here. (It's linked in the "I")

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to post this is as a comment, but if anyone wants to solve this it has been answered pretty well on super user:
https://superuser.com/questions/719677/how-to-use-gmail-tabs-with-imap